# Symfony2 twig forms

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Symfony2 uses some twig templates when rendering forms.
In particular, in order to render the *choice* form field collapsed, symfony2 uses the following snippet of code (from *form_div_layout.html.twig*):

```
{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder != '' ? placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}
```

In my application, I want to create a new form type, that extends the default collapsed choice type, but where choice list has custom formatting.

In other words, for my form field type, named **places_widget**, extending *choice_widget_collapsed* block but redefining *choice_widget_options*.

I already tried:

```
/* My first attempt */
{%- block places_widget -%}
    {% block choice_widget_options %}
      {{ block('choice_places_widget_options') }}
    {% endblock choice_widget_options %}

    {{ block('choice_widget_collapsed') }}
{%- endblock places_widget -%}

/* My other attempt */
{%- block places_widget -%}
    {{ block('choice_widget_collapsed', { 'choice_widget_options' => choice_places_widget_options }) }}
{%- endblock places_widget -%}

/* together with */
{%- block choice_places_widget_options %}
    // code here
{%- endblock choice_places_widget_options -%}
```

None of the two solutions is working, and actually I have the feeling I am doing things in the wrong way.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve the goal?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you actually using {%- -%} as tags?

Answer (score 0):

Forms can be customized using themes (see the doc here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig)

In your case, it seems you need to load your own theme with:
    `{% form_theme form _self %}`

Note that you could externalize these blocks in another file (refer to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template to see how to do that)